# Extending a vector asynchronously without temporary initialisation

Tags: asynchronous, rust

Assume I have an async function `f(usize) -> Future<Output = T>` and a vector `v` of length `n_old` such that `v[i] = f(i).await`. I would now like to extend this vector to length `n_new` while maintaining the `v[i] = f(i).await` invariant, and I would like to exploit the asynchronous nature of `f` while doing so. What's the best way to do this?

If `T` implements `Default`, then one way to do what I want is the following:

```
v.resize_with(n_new, Default::default);
futures::stream::iter((n_old..n_new).zip(v[n_old..n_new].iter_mut()))
    .for_each_concurrent(None, |(i, vi)| async move {
        *vi = f(i).await;
    })
    .await;
```

However, this feels a bit overly convoluted. Is there a more elegant approach?

Complete MWE: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e050df38de58d6376b103bb4d25afb6e

Comment: How would `split_at_mut` help?

Comment: the only way would be to use an not ordered storage than order it after by keeping the order expected. There is no silver bullet

Comment: on general advice you look you could use an hashmap instead of a vec

Comment: Actually, the iterator could be constructed more readably using `v.iter_mut().enumerate().skip(n_old)`. I assume `skip()` is implemented efficiently given that the underlying sequence allows random access.

Comment: Sorry, I read the question incorrectly in my previous comment. I thought you were trying to modify the old elements while adding the new elements at the same time.